# get author in blog posts?

Tags: customization, blog

What do I need to do in order to have the author name in the blog posts on my wordpress blog?

currently when I view a post it doesn't have the author that wrote the post.

Answer (score 0):

This will be somewhat dependent on where your `single` post view is stored, but you'd be looking to add something to the effect of:

```
<?php

echo __('Written by', 'text_domain') .' <a href="'. get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')) .'" rel="author" class="fn">'. get_the_author() .'</a>';
```

Comment: Where do I add this? How do I find that single post view?

Comment: @ThomasStringer Have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display

Answer (score 0):

The code needs to go in `single.php`, which you'll most likely find in your theme folder. If you are using a child theme, you might not see it; in which case, copy the file from the parent theme to your child theme folder.
The WordPress function you need is [the_author](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author), so to get the author's name, add something like this inside the loop:

```
 <p>This post was written by <?php the_author(); ?></p>
```